# AuthHttp class in angular2-jwt not present in 'npm i @auth0/angular-jwt'

Tags: angular

I have installed the @auth0/angular-jwt package and as in Anular2-jwt there is class called AuthHttp(which will add Bearer  automatically and also set into the Authorization header as well).

How can we achieve the same thing with @auth0/angular-jwt

Answer (score 1):

`AuthHttp` is no more in this module but you can achieve similar behavior with `@auth0/angular-jwt`. Try adding this configuration to you app module :

```
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
...

export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
}

@NgModule({
...

JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: { tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
      whitelistedDomains: ['http://localhost:8080'],
      blacklistedRoutes: [],
      headerName: 'x-auth-token',
      throwNoTokenError: true,
      skipWhenExpired: false,
      authScheme:'name of auth scheme' //default is Bearer  
}
    })
....
})
export class AppModule { }
```

For more details refer [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt).

Comment: I have added below in the AppModule,
JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: { tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
      whitelistedDomains: ['http://localhost:8080'],
      blacklistedRoutes: []
      }
    })

And in my Service i have added below code 
...
constructor(private http: Http, private authHttp: HttpClient) {
  }
getOrders() { 
this.authHttp
      .get('/api/orders')
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data), err => console.log(err));
}
...
But i am getting 404 GET http://localhost:4200/api/orders 404 (Not Found)
but when i am using http then it is able to hit the orders api

Comment: Can you try to set some dummy value for localStorage.setItem('access_token', 'value') before your service call.

Comment: Add you service url in `whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:4200']` hope its not  `localhost:8080` for you..

Comment: Can you share your code on stackblitz, actually it should work.